# SaltStack - How to conditionally enforce states?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, salt-stack

*This is a self-answered question.

Please provide edits, additional points of view and input if needed.*

What is the best practice for conditionally enforcing states (depending on other command outputs)?

Here's my case:

```
# vim: set syntax=yaml:

# Ensures that outbound connections are allowed for httpd
httpd:selinux:
    cmd.run:
        - name: /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Now, I only want to run this if SELinux is enabled (enforced).

Answer (score 1):

### 1)

One way of solving it is by using the `onlyif` parameter of [salt.states.cmd.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run):

```
# Ensures that outbound connections are allowed for httpd
httpd:selinux:
    cmd.run:
        - name: /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
        - onlyif:
            - 'if [[ $(getenforce) == "Disabled" ]]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi'      # if SELinux is disabled, then don't enforce this state
```

This is a very quick and easy way of solving this problem and as we're dealing with Shell commands in this example it is probably the most preferable way.
Please note that `onlyif` is dependent on the return status code of the command that is being tested, so if more flexibility is needed then this might not be what you're looking for.

### 2)

Another way is to access execution modules with jinja templating, wrap your state in this conditional:

```
{% if salt.selinux.getenforce() == "Disabled" %}
    httpd:selinux:
    ...
{% endif %}
```

This is a more flexible solution, but also takes up a bit more space.
More info on: [salt.modules.selinux.getenforce()](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.selinux.html#salt.modules.selinux.getenforce)